# Can't start Elasticsearch (fileInputStream Fail)

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, startup

I'm currently building up a test environment for HPE ALM Octane for my company. This Application uses Elasticsearch. Now I have the problem, that I can't start my Elasticsearchserver and I'm a bit at the end of my nerves ;).

Cause Octane works with Elasticsearch version 2.4.0, I'm also forced to work with this version.

**I get the following Error:**

[Error - Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRyhf.png)

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service;
   enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-21 09:40:50 CET; 1h 9min ago
   Process: 954 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch     
   -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid 
   -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} 
   -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.default.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} 
   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Process: 949 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 954 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1067)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:88)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialSettings(Bootstrap.java:218)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:257)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 elasticsearch[954]: Refer to the log for complete error details.
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 systemd 1 : elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 systemd 1 : elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
   Feb 21 09:40:50 linux-rfw5 systemd 1 : elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I **configured the absolute minimum**, that is possible. My Configurations:

1. elasticsearch.yml (/etc/elasticsearch/)
   1.1 cluster.name: octane_test
   1.2 node.name: elasticNode
   1.3 network.host: 127.0.0.1 (yes localhost, cause I'm running the octane server on the same host)
2. http.port: 9200 elasticsearch (/etc/sysconfig/)
       2.1 ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g (4 GB is 50% of the maximum memory)

I appreciate your help ;)
Joel

Comment: con you please share the log entry for when the error happens.. and probably a full error message from journalctl would also help.. the screenshot you've sent has very limited information.

Comment: added, thats all i get @MarcosMaia

Comment: hum.. so you mean you have nothing in the elasticsearch logs? and also if you tail journal with: 'journalctl -f' in the machine that's all you get?  I think this is most unlikely as your message states: Refer to the log for complete error details.

Comment: no I looked at both of them but they are empty @MarcosMaia